# Linux System Call write() in c language does not work?

Tags: c, linux, file, system-calls

I wrote the following code:

It should accept a file name and create it and write to it. Nothing happens.
I don't understand why. I tried searching and saw similar examples should work fine.
I am using VirtualBox with Xubuntu if that matters.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <errno.h> 
#include <string.h>

#define SIZE_4KB        4096
#define FILE_SIZE       16777216



/*Generate a random string*/
char* randomStr(int length)
{
        int i = -1;
        char *result;
        result = (char *)malloc(length);
        while(i++ < length)
        {
                *(result+i) = (random() % 23) + 67;
                if(i%SIZE_4KB)
                        *(result+i) = '\0';
        }
        return result;
}

void writeFile(int fd, char* data, int len, int rate)
{
        int i = 0;
        len--;
        printf("Writing...\n");
        printf("to file %d :", fd);
        while(i < len)
        {
                write(fd, data, rate);
                i += rate;
        }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
        int i = -1, fd;
        char *rndStr;
        char *filePath;      
        assert (argc == 2);
        filePath = argv[1];
        rndStr = randomStr(FILE_SIZE);
        printf("The file %s was not found\n", filePath);
        fd = open(filePath, O_CREAT, O_WRONLY);
        writeFile(fd, rndStr, FILE_SIZE, SIZE_4KB);
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you expect to happen?

Comment: I hope you realize that `if(i%SIZE_4KB)` means `if(i % SIZE_4KB != 0)`, i.e., `if(i` is *not* a multiple of `SIZE_4KB)`. (Currently, you're setting the vast majority of `rndStr` to null bytes.)

Comment: Learn to compile with all warnings and debugging info, i.e. with `gcc -Wall -g`, improve your code till no warnings are given, and use the `gdb` debugger (and perhaps the `valgrind` memory leak detector) to debug it.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch - Thanks for the constructive comment. I do use the dgb sometimes to debug, It did not help me in this case. I did not however try the -Wall command (I am rather new), this would be the second program I've written in the last two years in c language. This comment will help me improve my work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `open` call is wrong. Multiple flags are specified by combining arguments with OR. And, when you are creating a file, the third argument should be the permissions you wish the file to have. So your `open` call should be something like:

```
fd = open(filePath, O_CREAT | O_WRONLY, 0666);
if (fd < 0)
    Handle error…
```

You should always test return values from system calls and library functions to see if errors have occurred.

Comment: What is 0666 ? It does not look like a string or a number. Thanks for the great answer. I did not see the permissions explained in the examples I tried previously.

Comment: @ArthurWulfWhite: Integer literals beginning with `0` are interpreted as octal (base-8) constants; for example, `0666` means 6×8²+6×8+6. (Octals are not used very often, except for file-permissions, which are designed in an octal-friendly way: three bits for the owner's read/write/execute permissions, three for the group-owner's, and three for everyone else's.)

Comment: That is what I thought, so it expects an octal cause there are 3bits for each user type, read write and execute? Makes sense

Comment: @ArthurWulfWhite: The routine does not expect an octal, because the number passed to it is not octal or decimal or anything else; it is just a number (albeit represented in bits, so you could say it is binary). You could pass the same number, 438, in decimal, and it work work just as well. It is merely that octal is a convenient way for humans to view and write this field because it is coincidentally grouped into three sets of three bits, plus some others.

Comment: @EricPostpischil
Yeah, I meant that it expects 3bits for each user type, making octal the natural way to represent it. Thanks again for clearing things up and helping me understand the open() command better.